# Center Font Awesome Icons Vertically

Tags: css, font-awesome

How can I adjust the height of the Font Awesome social icons at the top right of [this page](http://www.photomobil.co.il/) so that they sit in the middle of the black bar and not at the bottom?  Adding padding-bottom: to .social raises them but also increases the depth of the black bar which I don't want.  Adding padding-bottom elsewhere has no effect.  Thank you!!

```
     .social {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-size: 0;
height: 28px;
}
.image-caption .social {
height: 33px;
padding:top: 10px;

}
.social li {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-left: 15px;

}
.footer .widget.single .social li {
margin: 0 3px
}
.text-center .social li {
margin: 0 2px
}
.social li a {
display: table
}
.social li a i {
text-align: center;
padding-top: 7px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
color: #aaa;
background: none;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
width: 28px;
height: 28px !important;
line-height: 1;
font-size: 13px;
-webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
-o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.social a:hover a:hover i {
background-color: #FFF
}
.social a:hover i {
color: #FFF
}
```

Comment: I can not access your site from Switzerland. Could you provide some html code instead?

Comment: Use line-height rule

Comment: Luis - line-height rule worked a treat!  Thank you so much!!

Comment: Aruloci - it's a different issue but I'm most concerned that you cannot access the site from Switzerland.  Please could you tell me what message you get?